# Finding the N-th term of a Cantor set of rational numbers efficiently

Tags: c++

George Cantor gave a proof that a set of rational numbers is countable. It is possible to find the n-th term of it using the method shown in this image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1honU.png). I have found the solution here [2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/n-th-term-of-george-cantor-set-of-rational-numbers/). But it is very slow for big numbers, as I have the n that can be up to 10^18. Is there any way to do this fast?

Comment: Please provide the code

Comment: http://massimozanetti.altervista.org/files/mydocs/kthRationalNumberCantorEnumeration.pdf

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you face is an algorithmic one.

If you try to navigate with a `den` and `num` variable, you'll need to take `10^18` steps. your program will never finish. (well, it might, but we won't be there anymore)

The first optimization you can do is to loop over the diagonals. You'll *only* need to iterate over roughly `10^9` diagonals. This is within the bounds of what you can compute on your PC. For each diagonal, compute the length, check whether it's within the range you are looking for, and if not go to next next diagonal.

The second optimization is a closed-form solution. Please see the .pdf in the comments.

Comment: the time limit is 0.2 seconds btw, can you please tell me, you think finding diagonals will to its job? (I am not very good at estimating time complexity). I tried the closed-form solution from the .pdf file, but the checking system said that in about a half of test cases the program gave a wrong answer. The reason is that a method of assigning numbers to each fraction is different than from such displayed at the image I provided, and I have no idea how to implement that.